# Using Context Provider with AsyncStorage (With Class Component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context, asyncstorage

I've been trying to develop the Settings page for my React Native app, but I have had a lot of trouble incorporating `AsyncStorage`. I know that the Context Provider is working as intended because in all components of my app the variables passed are what I expect. I want to be able to save the state of the settings even after refreshing the application or when I reopen the app, but for some reason the application is always resetting back to the initial state that is stored in my Context Provider. Here is a look at my code.

**SettingsContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, Component } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const SettingsContext = createContext();

export class SettingsProvider extends Component {
    
    state = {
        notifications: false,
        locationServices: false,
        private: false,
        darkMode: false,
    }

    // updates the state of notifications
    toggleNotifications = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@notifications', JSON.stringify(!this.state.notifications));
        this.setState({ notifications: !this.state.notifications });
    };

    // updates the state of locationServices
    toggleLocationServices = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@locationServices', JSON.stringify(!this.state.locationServices));
        this.setState({ locationServices: !this.state.locationServices });
    };

    // updates the state of private
    togglePrivate = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@private', JSON.stringify(!this.state.private));
        this.setState({ private: !this.state.private });
    };

    // updates the state of darkMode
    toggleDarkMode = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@darkMode', JSON.stringify(!this.state.darkMode));
        this.setState({ darkMode: !this.state.darkMode });
    };

    render() {
        const { notifications, locationServices, private, darkMode } = this.state;
        const { toggleNotifications, toggleLocationServices, togglePrivate, toggleDarkMode } = this;

        return (
            <SettingsContext.Provider value={{ notifications, locationServices, private, darkMode, toggleNotifications, toggleLocationServices, togglePrivate, toggleDarkMode }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </SettingsContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default SettingsContext;
```

**Settings.Js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Switch } from 'react-native';
import SettingsContext from '../utils/SettingsContext';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

class Settings extends Component {

    // stores current state of user's settings
    static contextType = SettingsContext;

    componentDidMount(){
        const notifications = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@notifications'));
        const locationServices = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@locationServices'));
        const private = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@private'));
        const darkMode = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@darkMode'));
    }

    render() {
        const { notifications, locationServices, private, darkMode, toggleNotifications, toggleLocationServices, togglePrivate, toggleDarkMode } = this.context;

        // stores current settings state
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <View>
                    {/* Settings Title */}
                    <Text style={styles.titleWrapper}> Settings </Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.optionsWrapper}>
                    {/* News Push Notifications */}
                    <Text> Push Notifications </Text>
                    <Switch
                        onValueChange={() => toggleNotifications()}
                        value={notifications} /> 
                </View>

                
                <View style={styles.optionsWrapper}>
                    {/* Location Services Title */}
                    <Text> Location Services </Text>
                    <Switch
                        onValueChange={() => toggleLocationServices()}
                        value={locationServices} />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.optionsWrapper}>
                    {/* Privacy */}
                    <Text> Private </Text>
                    <Switch
                        onValueChange={() => togglePrivate()}
                        value={private} />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.optionsWrapper}>
                    {/* Dark Mode */}
                    <Text> Dark Mode</Text>
                    <Switch
                        onValueChange={() => toggleDarkMode()}
                        value={darkMode} />
                </View>

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I honestly believe that the issue is coming with the `ComponentDidMount()` with how I am using the AsyncStorage.getItem() functions. I tried to create getter functions in the `SettingsContext` file, however, when I did that and used the arrow function as the value for the Switches, for some reason when I tried to toggle it, the value would stay on the initial state of the setting and not to change it.

I'm not really sure how to go about using the AsyncStorage.getItem() because I still want the state of the of the INITIAL settings to be false, but when a user begins to toggle the settings, that is when I want them to be changed and stored locally for them to have access to the newly changed settings. If someone could please help me understand where I am going wrong and the updates I need to make, I would really appreciate. This is the last addition needed for the project I am working on. Thanks!

Comment: your componentDidMount code doesn't make any sense. first, there's a typo, `SON` -> `JSON`, JSON.parse doesn't return a promise so there's nothing to await, and you're storing the result in a variable that doesn't get used. It's effectively a NOOP.

Comment: I've corrected the spelling mistake. I think I should create a state in the class component and use setState in the ComponentDidMount to then use them later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I've come up with the solution to my problem. I added an async componentDidMount and included the AsyncStorage.getItem() function to properly set the state of the settings. This way it is still global across the different components of my app and after refreshing, it checks this first.

```
import React, { createContext, Component } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const SettingsContext = createContext();

export class SettingsProvider extends Component {
    
    state = {
        notifications: false,
        locationServices: false,
        private: false,
        darkMode: false,
    }

    // updates the state of notifications
    toggleNotifications = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@notifications', JSON.stringify(!this.state.notifications));
        this.setState({ notifications: !this.state.notifications });
    };

    // updates the state of locationServices
    toggleLocationServices = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@locationServices', JSON.stringify(!this.state.locationServices));
        this.setState({ locationServices: !this.state.locationServices });
    };

    // updates the state of private
    togglePrivate = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@private', JSON.stringify(!this.state.private));
        this.setState({ private: !this.state.private });
    };

    // updates the state of darkMode
    toggleDarkMode = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@darkMode', JSON.stringify(!this.state.darkMode));
        this.setState({ darkMode: !this.state.darkMode });
    };

// retrieves the state of settings from AsyncStorage on intial app startup
async componentDidMount() {
    const notificationsStorage= JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@notifications'));
    if(notificationsStorage !== null){
        this.setState({notifications: notificationsStorage})
    }

    const locationServicesStorage= JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@locationServices'));
    if(locationServicesStorage !== null){
        this.setState({locationServices: locationServicesStorage})
    }

    const privateStorage= JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@private'));
    if(privateStorage!== null){
        this.setState({private: privateStorage})
    }
 }

    const darkModeStorage= JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@darkMode'));
    if(darkModeStorage !== null){
        this.setState({darkMode: darkModeStorage})
    }
 }

    render() {
        const { notifications, locationServices, private, darkMode } = this.state;
        const { toggleNotifications, toggleLocationServices, togglePrivate, toggleDarkMode } = this;

        return (
            <SettingsContext.Provider value={{ notifications, locationServices, private, darkMode, toggleNotifications, toggleLocationServices, togglePrivate, toggleDarkMode }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </SettingsContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default SettingsContext;
```